# How to use constraints in Symfony Forms making a field required?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, symfony-forms

Running Symfony 4 with Symfony Forms, I have defined a text field in a form builder:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
{
     // .... other fields
     $builder->add('referralCode', TextType::class, [
            'required' => true,
            'label' => 'Referral Code',
            'constraints' => [new NotBlank()],
            'attr' => [
                'placeholder' => 'Enter a six figures Referral Code (e.g. "6EQE7M")'
            ]
        ]);

}
```

According to docs and tutorials, the NotBlank-constraint should be used here. However, it does not work. If I submit the form without any data typed into this text field, no error is shown. Instead a null value will be send into the property of the entity.

What else needs to be done here?

Comment: Typically you would apply this sort of constraint directly to the entity itself.  Are you by any chance using validation groups?  How are you submitting?  The required=true will prevent the browser from submitting the form using a regular submit element.  And double check that you are getting a null and not a string with a space in it.

Comment: Could you show your controller method code? How do you pass data and check errors?

Comment: Your code looks good. It must be something else. Check for the 'validation_groups' option, maybe you forgot to keep the 'Default' in it? When you add a validation group it is a common mistake to forget the Default option! So 'validation_groups' => ['Default', 'your_custom_validation']

Comment: Did you call `$form->isValid()` ?

Comment: Please show us your controller action code.